# Promise not returning resolve from express app.get Nodejs

Tags: node.js, react-native, express, promise, request-promise

I'm trying to return a resolve or reject depending on if the promise was successful or not. I can't seem to figure out why this isn't returning the response. All I get from my promise is `[object Object]`. This is what I get in response.

Here's the code:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        var sql = "INSERT INTO usersinfo (firstname,lastname,email,number,latitude,longitude) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        conn.query(sql,[fname,lname,email,num,req.query.latitude,req.query.longitude], (err,result) => {
            if (err) {
                res.send('error')
                console.log(err,'there has been an error')
                reject('There was an error')
                return
            }else{
                console.log('inserted')
                resolve({ success:'true' })
            }
            res.end()
        })
    })
})
```

Where I'm fetching the url:

```
const res = await fetch(`http://MYIPADDRESS?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}`)
                console.log(res)
```

I don't seem to get what's wrong. And if I attach the `then((response) => console.log(response))` method I get an error in the expo app saying `There was an error sending log messages to your development environment PrettyFormatPluginError:value.hasOwnProperty is not a function. (In 'value.hasOwnProperty('tag')','value.hasOwnProperty is undefined)`

Comment: How does your second snippet relate to your first?

Comment: I don't think the router cares what the result of the route handler is, does it?  Express doesn't do anything with the return value of the handler.  `app.get('/', fn)` Installs a route handler for `/` so that express will call `fn` when a request comes in and it will pass  `req, res, next` to `fn` but it doesn't look at the return result, so it doesn't matter if you're returning a promise to express.  Who are you intending to consume the result of that promise?

Comment: What do you expect `await fetch()` to evaluate to? Did you just forget to call `res.send({ success: true })`?

Comment: @trincot, good point.  Or maybe the intent was `res.send(await new Promise(....))` or `return new Promise(....).then(result => res.send(result))`

Comment: @Evert The second snippet is where I'm sending a request to the first.

Comment: @trincot I would like to receive the object `{ success:'true }`

Comment: @Wyck can that be done? Should I wrap the entire promise into `res.send` ? Would that then return the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a promise. The `send` method can be called asynchronously -- when the response is ready:

```
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    var sql = "INSERT INTO usersinfo (firstname,lastname,email,number,latitude,longitude) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    conn.query(sql,[fname,lname,email,num,req.query.latitude,req.query.longitude], (err,result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error');
            console.log(err,'there has been an error');
        } else {
            res.send({ success:'true' }); // <---
            console.log('inserted');
        }
    });
});
```

NB: also, there is no need to call `res.end()` as `res.send()` already implies that.

On the client side you'll have to await the JSON content to be generated:

```
const response = await fetch(`http://MYIPADDRESS?latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}`);
const result = await response.json(); // <---
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you!!!. This worked